# Not getting expected results with pow() in C++

Tags: c++, pow

I am doing a homework assignment for my C++ class, and am trying to do what I consider a fairly simple math function, but I'm getting stumped because it is not returning what I expect it to return. Basically, it's just an APR problem and I am trying to convert from APR to monthly interest. My instructor has given us this formula to calculate this:

- monthlyInterest = ((APR / 100) + 1)^(1/12)

So this is the code I am using. I separated yearlyInterest from the monthlyInterest calculation because I was making sure I wasn't making a simple mistake:

```
double balance, payment, APR;
cin >> balance >> payment >> APR;
const double yearlyInterest = (APR / 100) + 1;
const double monthlyInterest = pow(yearlyInterest, 1/12)
```

Using the inputs 1000, 100, and 19.9, the results I get in my physical calculator, and what I am expecting are:

1. yearlyInterest ~1.19
2. monthlyInterest ~1.015...

But the result my debugger is giving me is:

1. yearlyInterest ~1.19
2. monthlyInterest = 1

So basically, I am asking why my monthlyInterest is incorrect? I don't believe it is a type issue because pow() will output a double. Also, I don't think that the decimal should overflow the double type, it's not that big and I only need a few digits of accuracy anyway. So if anyone can help me determine the mistake I made, I would appreciate it.

Sidenote: I have included the following. I use  instead of  because it is what I learned on. If this is a problem, I can change it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this line:

```
const double monthlyInterest = pow(yearlyInterest, 1/12)
```

`1/12` gets rounded to 0 (because it's integer division) and the result is `1`. Replace with:

```
const double monthlyInterest = pow(yearlyInterest, 1.0/12)
```

Mind the `.`.

Comment: Gah! Silly me, I should have noticed that. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3):

`1/12` and `APR` are performing integer division.

If you explicitly use floating point numbers you'll get your expected results.

Instead of `1/12` use `1/12.` (notice decimal point)

and instead of `APR/100` use `APR/100.` (notice decimal point)

Answer (score 1):

One thing is clear and that is that `1/12` == 0 (try `1./12`).

Comment: Can we spell `1.0` as `1.0` rather than `1.` please, especially around beginners.

Comment: You can, but I prefer it this way. Especially around beginners to emphasise the importance of one dot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Danger, Will Robinson! `1/12` is not the same as `1.0/12.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the expression `1/12` return a float value to force floating point division instead of integer division.

change:

```
const double monthlyInterest = pow(yearlyInterest, 1/12);
```

to:

```
const double monthlyInterest = pow(yearlyInterest, 1.0/12);
```

---

```
const double monthlyInterest = pow(yearlyInterest, 1/12);
```

integer division of `1/12` truncates the fractional result to `0`. Thus the above line would be processed as

```
const double monthlyInterest = pow(yearlyInterest, 0);
```

and a number raised to the 0 power equals 1. Thus in your case **monthlyInterest** is assigned the value 1.